# Change Textbox text from another frame(container)

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I see here lot of similar question, but I still not find answer that help me in situation.

I have two frame(lets say `FrameChild`), one is "in" another(practically FrameChild is in this frame, lets say `FrameMain`).

When I insert all parameters in `FrameChild` and tap on button witch is on bottom of FrameMain I call method that return string... 
Now when i get string i need to change textbox text in `FrameChild`

I have tray many way.

First idea was something like:

```
FrameChild frm = new FrameChild;
frm.textbox.text = "somestring";
```

But nothing happen.
Than i thing use some property.

in `FrameChield`:

```
public string setTicNo
{
     set
        {
           textBox.Text = value;  
        }
    }
```

in `FrameMain`:
    FrameChild frm = new FrameChild;
    frm.setTicNo = "somestring";

When i debbuging I get value, but textbox still is empty...

On the end I try to bind textbox text on setTicNo;

```
public string setTicNo
{
     get
        {
            return setTicNo;
        }
     set
        {
           setTicNo = value;  
        }
 }
```

Xaml:

```
Text = {Binding setTicNo, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}
```

(here i try use more bindings, but every time i get infinite loop.

Please help , I not have more ideas..

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try building a single view model and bind it to both frames, if it was passed by ref which is the default it will change the value once you do.

A side note implement a INOTIFYPROPERTYCGANGED in the View model